# Los dos usos de la palabra 'arrebatada'

Tags: significado, humor

Acabo de descubrir **Les Luthiers**, un grupo de comedia argentina.  En el prologo de su composicion [*Perdonala (0:47s)*](http://youtu.be/bYLWTxNgY6o), dicen lo siguiente:

> Donde dice de inspiración ***arrebatada, como*** otros compositores románticos debe decir ***arrebatada a*** otros compositores románticos...

No entiendo el chiste aqui.  ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre los dos usos de la palabra "arrebatada"?  ¿Dónde está la broma y por qué es chistoso?

Comment: +1 por la sutileza de la pregunta. Y por el buen gusto...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El primer significado de `arrebatada`, como adjetivo, significa `impetuosa`. Y se utiliza para comparar su inspiración con la de los otros compositores románticos. El segundo significado se refiere a `arrebatada a`, como verbo, que significa robado, plagiado, copiado o quitado a los otros compositores románticos.

La broma radica en que el periódico se olvidó de la preposición `a` en `arrebatada a` y por ello tuvo que publicar una fe de erratas, para corregir el error. Con la ausencia de esta preposición cambia totalmente el significado de la oración, y cambia lo que era un elogio por una descalificación.

Answer (score 1):

Inspiración `arrebatada como` otros compositores románticos. Ahí está comparando la obra del personaje con la calidad de los otros compositores románticos. La fe de errata dice `arrebatada a` otros compositores románticos ahí esta diciendo que el personaje le robo,plagió, copió la obra a los otros compositores románticos. El chiste radica en el juego de palabras que se uso en la publicación original para vanagloriar al autor y en la fe de errata lo que hace es destruir al autor por decirlo de alguna manera

Answer (score 1):

> Inspiración arrebatada, como ...

es un halago que consiste en poner la inspiración de Mastropiero al nivel de otros compositores románticos. En cambio, con la preposición *a* aparece un cambio radical

> Inspiración arrebatada a

significa que plagió (robó) las obras de dichos compositores.